# custom module page -- i need it to use a predefined panels page layout

Tags: 7, panels

I've got this:

```
function foo_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['facadmin/directory'] = array(
        'title' => 'Faculty & Staff Directory',
        'page callback' => 'foo_facstaff_directory',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;    
}
```

Which then does this:

```
function foo_facstaff_directory() {
    $content = foo-make-html();
    $page = array();
    $page['#markup'] = $content;
    return $page;
}
```

I'd like this page to use a predefined panels template, but when I set 'facadmin/directory' as a selection rule, it doesn't do the smart thing automatically and just dumps the html into the content region -- no panels.

Help?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a custom block and put that into a standard layout instead.